# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

[error thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z5G9.jpg)
[photo of storyboard and the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UxyM.png)

I'm trying to check if a person exists for a certain date clicked on a calendar (each person has a date in the calendar associated with them), and if he doesn't a segue to a different controller. If he does I segue elsewhere. This problem arises when the person doesn't exist. I attached my code below and the problem is the performSegue in the else statement.

I'm really new to this so please explain as simply as possible! Appreciate it in advance.

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
        self.delegate?.dateSelected(dateStart: date)
        let person = containsHost(date: date)
        if (person != nil) {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "planReceipt", sender: person) 
        } else { //check sender and logic
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "modal", sender: nil) //DOESN'T WORK
        }

    }
```

Comment: Debug your code: Set the Exception Breakpoint

Comment: is this equivalent to the error thread I've shown? Could it be due to me not having a navigation controller?

Answer (score 1):

Check you didn't set up your segue identifiers with uppercase 
"PlanReceipt" in the storyboard. I've done that before.

Comment: It's actually the other segue that's not working. i.e the modal one. I've also double checked.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the storyboard. Either your segues - "planReceipt" and "createPlan" don't exist or change the sender: nil to sender: self.

Comment: I did this but it still doesn't seem to be working. I've added a photo for the error thread if that would help?